# Присвоение переменной возвращаемого значения метода

Tags: java, android, методы, переменные, класс

Есть строки:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(this);
mCrimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
```

Если я правильно понимаю, в первой строке происходит присвоение переменной того, что возвращает метод get().
Но в таком случае как мы вызываем с помощью этой переменной метод getCrimes(), который находится в том же классе, что и метод get()?
Или в первой строке происходит что-то совсем другое?

Comment: А что необычного в вызове `getCrimes()` ? Класс `CrimeLab` содержит нестатический метод `getCrimes()`, у объекта `crimeLab`, у которого тип `CrimeLab`, вызывается метод `getCrimes()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый метод

```
CrimeLab.get(this);
```

Является статичным методом **класса**. Возвращает **объект** класса (создает, если ранее не был создан).

Второй метод

```
crimeLab.getCrimes();
```

Является методом **экземпляра** класса. То есть вызываться может только из конкретного объекта.

Аналогия:

Класс `Кролик`.

**Статичный** метод `bool canRun()` может быть вызван как `Кролик.canRun();`. Нам не нужно видеть перед собой конкретного кролика, чтобы сказать, умеет ли он бегать.

**Метод экземпляра** класса `String getName()` **не** может быть вызван у класса, нам нужен **конкретный** кролик, чтобы узнать, как его зовут. То есть вызов будет:

```
Кролик кролик = Кролик();
String name = кролик.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете экземпляр класса CrimeLab с именем crimeLab.

Метод get возвращает объект CrimeLab.

Далее crimeLab.getCrimes() возвращает другой объект (серее всего список mCrimes), ссылку на который вы сохраняете в переменой mCrimes.